# Can you use an Azure AD identity to log into the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've created some Microsoft Live accounts for managing my Azure subscriptions (I've got five).  I can log in using, for example, joe@mycompany.com and manage my web services using the **public portal**. I think I've got the hang of Azure Active Directory and the Domain Services that go along with it. So now I'm wondering, can I associate my domain ('mycompany.com') with an Azure Active Directory in my **corporate portal**, add my user 'joe' to it, and use 'joe@mycompany.com' to sign into the portal?  That is, will the Azure Portals use Azure Active Directory for logins?

Answer (score 0):

**The Azure Portal allows users to sign in with both Azure AD Accounts AND Microsoft accounts** (aka MSAs, LiveIDs, @outlook.com).

If you [associate your domain with an Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain), you'll be able to log in to the Azure portal with your Azure AD account.

It is important to note that **if you have a joe@mycompany.com Microsoft account and a joe@mycompany.com Azure AD account** (which you get by adding the mycompany.com domain to an Azure AD tenant and then creating joe@mycompany.com that tenant), **you effectively have tow DIFFERENT ACCOUNTS**. When you type in joe@mycompany.com, you'll see a prompt like this one:

[image: Dual MSA and Azure AD]

You'll have to make sure you pick the right one since your existing Azure subscriptions will be associated with your MSA and any new ones you create with your Azure AD account will, by default, not be accessible to your MSA.

Your best bet is to setup an Azure AD tenant, **migrate your Azure subscriptions from your MSA to your Azure AD tenant** by [transfering ownership of the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer) and ensure all new subscriptions are created with Azure AD accounts (and not MSAs). At that point, you can always pick Organizational account and not have to worry about which which Azure subscription is linked to which account.

Other relevant info:

- [Comprehensive explanation of MSAs, Azure AD and Azure Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory#accounts-that-you-can-use-to-sign-in)
- [Creating an Azure subscription using an Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/sign-up-organization)